# Pandas and HDF5, querying a table, string containing '&' character

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I've ran into a problem grouping with HDFStore which turned out to extend to selecting rows based on strings that contain the '&' character. This should illustrate the problem

```
>>> from pandas import HDFStore, DataFrame
>>> df = DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'test & test', 'c' , 'b', 'e'], 
                   'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})
>>> store = HDFStore('test.h5')
>>> store.append('test', df, format='table', data_columns=True)
>>> df[df.a == 'test & test']
```

```
     a              b
4    test & test    5
```

```
>>> store.select('test', 'a="test & test"')
```

```
Int64Index([], dtype='int64')   Empty DataFrame
```

Now I'm wondering if I'm missing something from the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#querying-a-table) or if this is a bug.

Comment: bug.... see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6351; I don't think hard to fix, we have a pre-parser that basically subsitutes certain expressions; need to have it not do that inside quotes

Comment: This was just merged in ...... so pls give a try with master!

Answer (score 1):

As commented, this is now fixed (since pandas 0.14):

```
In [11]: df[df.a == 'test & test']
Out[11]:
             a  b
4  test & test  5

In [12]: store.select('test', 'a="test & test"')
Out[12]:
             a  b
4  test & test  5
```

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion h5py is a much more robust python module for HDF5 files than pandas. 
http://www.h5py.org/

Comment: The question is about how to use Pandas.  This answer has nothing to do with the problem at hand.